# Mysql search query returning one result from databse

Tags: php, mysql, forms, search

I am developing a small search engine from one of my small database table. But whatever I search it display only one result. Please help me to do that correctly...

Thanks

HTML form:

```
<form action="search_page.php" method="post">
    <select name="search_type" id="search_type" required>
        <option value="*" selected disabled>Search By...</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="mailing_address">Mailing Address</option>
        <option value="permanent_address">Permanent Address</option>
        <option value="current_prof_1">Profession</option>
    </select>
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search Here..." required>
    <button type="submit" name="search_start" class="search_button">Search</button>
</form>
```

And php query code:

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['search_start'])) {
        $search_by = $_POST['search_type'];
        $search_for = $_POST['search'];

        $search_query="SELECT * FROM member Where $search_by like '%$search_for%'";
        $search_pull = mysqli_query($connection, $search_query);
        $search_count = mysqli_num_rows($search_pull);
        if ($search_count > 0 ) {
            $serial = 1;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_pull)) {
                $member_id = $row["id"];
                $name = ucwords($row["name"]);
                $batch = $row["batch"];

                $search_members ="<tr>";
                $search_members .="<td>$serial</td>";
                $search_members .="<td>$name</td>";
                $search_members .="<td>$batch</td>";
                $search_members .="</tr>";
                ++$serial;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I would first focus on that SQL injection vulnerability if I were you...

Comment: Member id. What do you do with that

Comment: The problem is fixed. Thanks everybody.

@Strawberry, I was just practicing the search process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
$search_members ="<tr>";
```

to

```
$search_members .="<tr>";
```

You are initializing the print string every time in the loop.

You need it to be concatenated with the respective record.

With this typo, your result is every time getting over written with the latest record in while loop.

Also, please initialize

`$search_members = '';`

before the while loop in case you have zero rows returned, it should not return undefined variable error.

Comment: And don't forget to initialize `$search_members` to an empty string outside of the loop

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is fixed. I have an empty string outside the loop already.

Answer (score 0):

REplace your code with:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search_start'])) {
    $search_by = $_POST['search_type'];
    $search_for = $_POST['search'];

    $search_query="SELECT * FROM member Where $search_by like '%$search_for%'";
    $search_pull = mysqli_query($connection, $search_query);
    $search_count = mysqli_num_rows($search_pull);
    if ($search_count > 0 ) {
        $serial = 1;
        $search_members='';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_pull)) {
                $member_id = $row["id"];
                $name = ucwords($row["name"]);
                $batch = $row["batch"];

                $search_members .="<tr>";
                $search_members .="<td>$serial</td>";
                $search_members .="<td>$name</td>";
                $search_members .="<td>$batch</td>";
                $search_members .="</tr>";
                ++$serial;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks amit... already solved but your answer is also correct...

Comment: @pol Please accept the answer. so it will be helpful for someone.

Comment: Hi amit, actually both answer are same. Moreover I am having problem to accept multiple answer at the same time.